# How did $1/3$ comes from in the volume of tetrahedron?

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

The volume of tetrahedron is given by
$$\frac{1}{3}(\text{Area of base})(\text{vertical height})$$

Similar formula is applicable for the volume of a cone.

I know that a right circular cone can be enveloped in a right circular cylinder with common base and height but can't still corelated their volumes.

Can someone explain or prove where did this $\frac13$ come in the formula of volume of tetrahedron.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want a formal proof or an intuitive explanation/geometric argument?

Comment: A similar question: [How to calculate the volume of an arbitrary pyramid without calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634905/how-to-calculate-the-volume-of-an-arbitrary-pyramid-without-calculus?rq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Volume of Pyramid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100715/volume-of-pyramid) among many others.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a geometric intuition where a cube is divided into three pyramids with the same base:

https://www.polyhedra.net/en/model.php?name-en=three-pyramids-that-form-a-cube

And because three of them fit into a cube with the same "height" and "base" it is a third of that Volume ($V=b*h/3$).

This can also be proven using calculus but I think this is rather what you asked for.

A [video with an accesible proof](https://youtu.be/FifeXRpiFTI).